# backup mongodb using ansible - using mongodump?

Tags: mongodb, ansible, database-backups, mongodump

We need to develop new system that using ansible code to backup few data bases to local windows machine.

I tried unsuccessfully to use "win_command" module and try to transfer the complete command but it didn't work.

```
  - name: Backup MongoDb    
    win_command:
      free_form: mongodump.exe --username 'user' --password 'password' --authenticationDatabase 'admin' -d "db_name" -o "path_to_db_backup"
      chdir: path_to_mongodump.exe
```

I find some ansible module that related to mongodb but none of them are related to mongodump.

well, my question is how I can use ansible to backup mongodb DBs with or without mongodump.

thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Im not get any error, but I cant see any backup in the detestation folder.
like nothing happen

Comment: What if you launch directly the dump command on the target machine?

Comment: @zigarn this is waht I trying to do in the code that I added, no ?!

Comment: I propose to test it directly, without using ansible to verify it works first, then you can execute it through ansible.

Comment: I tested it on the local win machine and its work..
now I need to do it in ansible